# How to do friend ORM model in fuelphp

Tags: many-to-many, fuelphp, self-reference

I need to do a self referencing many to many relationship in fuelphp orm model.
In the application a user can have other users as friends.

I have a users table, and friends table. Users table stores the main information about the user, the friends table a single row stores the relationship between two users.

Friends table has fields | id | user_id1 | user_id2 |.

Im totaly stuck on how to create a many to many relationship self referencing on the user.

Here are the fuelphp orm relation docs: http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/relations/many_many.html

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply specify two relations in the `$_many_many` property.

```
protected static $_many_many = array(
    'children' => array(
        'key_from' => 'id',
        'key_through_from' => 'parent_id',
        'table_through' => 'my_relation_table',
        'key_through_to' => 'child_id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_User',
        'key_to' => 'id',
    ),
    'parents' => array(
        'key_from' => 'id',
        'key_through_from' => 'child_id',
        'table_through' => 'my_relation_table',
        'key_through_to' => 'parent_id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_User',
        'key_to' => 'id',
    ),
);
```

Notice that `key_through_from` and `key_through_to` are flipped in each relation definition.